# How to download the files data attached to webform

Tags: entities, webforms, files

I have **webform** with text fields and file **upload field**. How can i *download* the all the documents which was  uploaded through this webform.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using these modules:

[Webform Protected Downloads](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_protected_downloads)

> This module provides a handy solution for the following situation:
>
> - you want to offer some files for download to either anonymous or    registered users
> - you don't want those files to be publicly accessible
> - you want to collect some data before granting access to the files
> - you want to be sure that the user gives a valid email address

[Webform2PDF](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform2pdf)

> The Webform2PDF Drupal module is an extension of the Webform module.
>   It can be used to generate PDF document from the results of a form.
>   The generated PDF document can be attached to the form summary e-mail
>   sent by Webform module, or it can be downloaded from the /Results/
>   page. Different PDF templates can be set for each form.